# PHP: выделение элементов массива в отдельный массив и последующая сортировка

Tags: php, search, find

Приветствую

подскажите, есть ли в php функционал:

1. найти в массиве элементы по некоторому алгоритму (описанный как
   функтор) и выделить в отдельный массив
2. отсортировать найденный массив по некоторому алгоритму (описанный как функтор)

подозреваю, что одной такой функии нет, но хотя бы по 1 функции на 1 этап есть?

очень не хочется этап 1 через for делать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-column.php)
2. [array_multisort()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-multisort.php)

Пример использования:

```
$arr = [
    ["menu" => "ббббб", "link" => "/catalog/6"],
    ["menu" => "яяяяя", "link" => "/catalog/5"],
    ["menu" => "ааааа", "link" => "/catalog/10"],
    ["menu" => "ууууу", "link" => "/catalog/2"]
];

$key = 'link'; // Ключ, по которому сортировать
array_multisort(array_column($arr, $key), SORT_NATURAL, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'menu' => 'ууууу' 
      'link' => '/catalog/2' 
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'menu' => 'яяяяя' 
      'link' => '/catalog/5' 
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'menu' => 'ббббб' 
      'link' => '/catalog/6' 
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'menu' => 'ааааа' 
      'link' => '/catalog/10'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `array_filter` (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php)
2. `usort` (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php)

   Тут сравнение всех функций сортировки: 
   http://php.net/manual/ru/array.sorting.php